# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, iteradores

Quiero hacer un iterador doble. Pero no sé el motivo por el que no funciona. Este es mi código:

```
tipo = ['ward', 'complete', 'average', 'single']
distance = [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1]
for t, d in tipo, distance:
    clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(
        n_clusters=None, linkage=t, distance_threshold=d)
    clustering = clustering.fit(puntos)
    plot_dendrogram(clustering, truncate_mode='level', p=3)
```

El mensaje de error ha sido corto y se produce en la tercera línea (en el bucle for):

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

Iterar en dos listas al mismo tiempo no funciona: `for t, d in tipo, distance:`.

Pero puedes juntar las dos listas en una lista bidimensional con un [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#zip), y entonces puedes hacer: `for t, d in zip(tipo, distance):`